# OpenCV - How to remove small line segments from contour?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, contour

Is there a way to remove small line segments from a contour?

For example, in this image, the largest contour is specified by green color and it's approximation is specified by blue color:

[image]

As contour is a set of Points, I guess we can do something to remove segments of contours that are in red circles. For example by detecting and removing small lines or small sub contours or another way. But I do not know how I can do it.

Please remember I want to remove them after finding contour and not before that. Do you know how I can remove them? Or any idea?

Comment: How I'd go about it is sit down with a piece of paper, make a sketch, and Mathematically define conditions for these outliers, e.g. something to do with the jump in either coordinate (here looking at how many points you've got in the outliers would help). And then simply filter the spikes out. Tried anything like that?

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: @tobes I could not remove them in regular way,I try to find foreground by `grabcut` and then find it's contour.

Comment: Can you upload the original image if possible?

Comment: @JeruLuke Sorry! I could not find the original.

Comment: @hasanghaforian Alright you could get another bill/receipt with a simillar background and upload it

Answer (score 1):

I've found that contourArea is good for removing small, isolated contours.  This snippet illustrates how you might proceed:

```
findContours(edges, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

...

```
// Prune contours
vector<vector<Point> > prunedContours;
for (size_t i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++)
     {
         if (contourArea(contours[i]) > minArea)
         {
           prunedContours.push_back(contours[i]);
         }
     }
```

If the "loops" or extraneous contour regions are part of the larger contour of interest, take a look at [approxPolyDP](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#approxpolydp).  It's possible that a coarse approximation of your original contour can omit the extraneous features.

Comment: If you see image,you can see that also approximation  has unwanted lines.

Comment: I'll assume you've increased approxPolyDP's epsilon value? The green contour should "degenerate" to  four-sided polygon at high enough epsilons.  Additionally, the blue contour appears to have a loop in the lower left corner.  This suggests that you've not pruned your original contour list by area.